# Parsing XML = variable for Intent

Tags: android, xml

I would like use parsing XML (the file is on the Net) to get a title in a listView and on the click call an Activity with a part of my parsing.

Example :
My xml contents :

```
<title>Video 1</title><link>http://video.mp4</link>
<title>Video 2</title><link>http://video2.mp4</link>
```

ListView show : Video 1, Video 2
And on the click it launch the link (via an `intent.putExtra`).

How can I do to make this ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse your XML into a map. `Map<VideoName,VideoLink>`
2. Set the list text to the keys of your map.
3. Create a onClick listener for your list in which you should get the key that was clicked and retrieve the value and start the intent.

Here is how you do it:

```
final HashMap<String, String> xmlMap = xmlToMap();
final String[] titleArray=(String[]) xmlMap.keySet().toArray();
ListView lv=new ListView(this);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,titleArray));
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
    {
        String videoTitle=titleArray[pos];
        String videoLink=xmlMap.get(titleArray[pos]);
    }
});


HashMap<String, String> xmlToMap()
{
    HashMap<String, String> xmlMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // Parse the xml document you have.
    // In the xml parsing loop 
        // Every 'title' tag you read and corresponding 'link' 
        //tag you read you insert an element into map
            String title=""; // Every 'title' tag you read
            String link=""; // Corresponding 'link' tag 
            xmlMap.put(title, link);
    // Loop ends
    return xmlMap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this help, list text to the key ? Do you have a tutorial for this ? Thanks

Comment: Extract the keys from your map and map them into an array.Go through the ListView tutorial [HERE](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). Read setListAdapter. The adapter takes an array, this is where the array of keys is used.

Comment: If I understand correctly :
I should do :
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("titre", PARSING_BUT_DONT_KNOW_HOW);
map.put("url", PARSING_BUT_DONT_KNOW_HOW);
listItem.add(map);

String[] videoname = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.videoname_array);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,videoname));